# How to know if this code was executed correctly?

Tags: php, image

Im using the following php code to upload an image to the server, the thing is I dont know how to make a "Success" or "Error" echo so I can handle each situation:

```
<?php
$msg = " ".var_dump($_FILES)." ";
$new_image_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/images/" . $new_image_name);

?>
```

This is the response array Im getting:

```
["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "profile_698.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php0TFnhg"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1361497)
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: if(condition){...} else {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

So you can check if the function move_uploaded_file return true or false.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/images/" . $new_image_name)){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you can modify the response you're receiving. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for `move_uploaded_file` it returns a bool. Specifically it returns `true` on success.

Set the value returned by `move_uploaded_file` to a variable and then modify your response array.

```
$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/images/" . $new_image_name);
```

You did not show how you are sending that response back. Update your post with that code and I can update my answer.